# WPF bind collection of collections to a listview and group on parent collection object property

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

I cannot get the databinding to work properly for the following scenario:

**Model** - a collection of `DetailEntries`, along with some collective properties form a `DailyDetailSet`:

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class DailyDetailsSet
{
    public DailyDetailsSet(DateTime startDate, ObservableCollection<DailyDetailEntry> entries)
    {
        this.StartDate = startDate;
        this.Entries = entries;
    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; }

    public decimal TotalHours => this.Entries.Sum(x => x.TotalHours);
    public string TotalHoursFormatted => this.TotalHours.ToFormattedDurationString();

    public ObservableCollection<DailyDetailEntry> Entries { get;  }

    public DetailsGroupingHeader DetailsGroupingHeader => new DetailsGroupingHeader(this.StartDate, this.TotalHours);

}

[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class DailyDetailEntry
{
    //some properties
}

public class DetailsGroupingHeader
{
    //Some text and color properties and overriden Equals() method to allow grouping
}
```

**ViewModel** - a collection of `DailyDetailsSet` is retrieved from database:

```
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class EntryListViewModel : ViewModelBase
       {
         public ObservableCollection<DailyDetailsSet> EntrySets { get; set; }
       }
    }
```

A view should contain a Listbox, which should contain all the `DailyDetailEntries`, grouped into groups for each day, based on the DetailsGroupingHeader (it compares the entry date really)

**View**:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Sets" Source="{Binding Path=EntrySets}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DetailsGroupingHeader" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
    </UserControl.Resources>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource Sets}"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="5">

            <ListView.View >
                    <GridView >
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartTimeFormatted}" Header="Start" Width="60"  />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment"  >
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="False" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" 
                                                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Name.EntryColor}"  FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name.TotalHoursFormatted}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Name.EntryColor}"  FontWeight="Bold" Text=" hours - "/>
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Name.EntryColor}" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name.EntryDateFormatted}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Name.EntryColor}" FontWeight="Bold" Text=" Entries: "/>
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=Name.EntryColor}" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Now, it doesn't fully work - I cannot get the `CollectionViewSource` to work based on the inner collection (each EntrySet contains Entries collection which should be the actual data source - the EntrySet is used for grouping and custom group header display).

The current code gives the following result:
[image]
So, this shows that the binding 'sort of' works, but the groups don't contain the actual entries inside (only the one single property which is identical in the `DailyDetailEntry` and `DailyDetailSet`).

How do I make the listview use the collection property of a collection as the items source?
I tried lots of different declarations for ItemsSource in binding, including specifying Path, or a syntax like that `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Sets" Source="{Binding Path=EntrySets/Entries}">`, but in most cases the result is even worse .

Comment: groups contain 1 entry each. and I suppose that 
"8:0" is a StartTimeFormatted of a single entry from group "8:0 hours"

Comment: @ASh - no, I can see in the code behind that each of the `DailyDetailsSet` contains more than 1 entry. The 8:0 is the 'TotalHoursFormatted' property from the `DailyDetailsSet`

Comment: You only get name in the grouping, Ash is correct. I think you might do better to construct a collection of an object you group on which itself has a collection of the data for that. Rather than using grouping and collectionview like you are.

Comment: @Andy, sorry, not sure what you have in mind. It seems to me I do have a collection of objects I group on (`DailyDetailSets`) which have collection of data - `DailyDetailEntry`.

Comment: It seems you are creating new instance of group for each element. Then by default reference comparer will not group more than 1 item. You can either implement `IComparer` (I think, not sure which interface is right) to return `0` for *same* groups or rather (better) store groups in `Dictionary<>`, then you can reuse same instance of group for several items.

Comment: If you want to show a collection inside a collection AND you want more than one field in the grouping then I would set grouping and groupstyle aside. Define a DayViewModel. Give that a property for the sub collection ( and it's own fields). Call that DaysEntries. Make these match what you expect to see in the view. Bind an outer itemscontrol of some sort like a listbox to a collection of DayViewModel. In it's template, bind a listview or some such to DaysEntries. Just define an expander in your item template of the outer control rather than all that groupstyle stuff.

Comment: @mm8 - I am happy to upgrade my example, however I am not sure which of the M, V or C should I work on? unless you mean a sample standalone POC app:)